# Reverting a git merge -s ours

Tags: git, merge, revert

I want to revert a merge because instead of using `git merge -s recursive -X ours`, I've used `git merge -s ours`.

I've read [this blog post](http://progit.org/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) about reverting merges, but it doesn't seem to work for my case.

So, I have the `master` branch, and then the `topic` branch. At some point I merged `master` into `topic`, and then merged `topic` into `master`. When I merged `master` into `branch`, I had a conflict on a file, but I figured it didn't do anything important so I thought I say git to skip it, and use my version. That's when I used `git merge -s ours`, instead of `git merge -s recursive -X ours`, which I found out today that it ignored everything one of my team mates did.

Now, I'm trying to revert this merge:

```
git checkout master
git revert -m 2 c475f0ac
```

This is indeed bringing in the tree the changes ignored in my merge (my team mate's changes). The problem is that now, my changes are no more in the tree. I've tried reverting the revert, but no success.

Any suggestion on how to revert such a merge?

Comment: Is there any possibility you could `reset --hard` both master and topic to their state before the merge?

Comment: Not quite. The merge has been pushed. I guess what I can do is to revert the merge with `--no-commit` so that I can fix the changes and then commit the revert.

Comment: Update. That's exactly what I did. Reverted with --no-commit, fixed the changes and then commit. It worked fine at that time.

Comment: *bump* @VonC. @Ionut: I'm afraid @VonC never got noticed of your reply since you didn't use his @name

Comment: I didn't know SO is using @usernames to notify about changes. And honestly I still doubt it does. Anyway, my comment wasn't intended for @VonC, but to anyone who comes across this question.

Answer (score 1):

The revert subcommand makes a new commit to undo the specified commit, this usually is complicated for revert merge commits

You can set the tree to the state of any specific commit, search the merge commit (is c475f0ac  ?) and then set the tree to the state parent of that commit (note the dot at the end of the command, it's important):

```
git checkout c475f0ac^ .
```

If you want to set the state to different parent of the commit, you should use

```
git checkout c475f0ac^2 .
```

And so on. 
You will find useful the gitk command to analyze the commits before proceed (to choose the commit that you want):

```
gitk c475f0ac
```

After setting the state to the previous commit, you can commit

```
git commit --message 'restored tree to state previous to merge commit c475f0ac'
```

And then push

```
git push
```